# Content disappears when navigating to previous view/state on Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I've created a starter app with side menu using Ionic based on AngularJS.

The basic navigation layout of the app suppose to be:

- main page
- ion-side-menu that shows our company's service types as a list. (when item is clicked go to:)
- company services list for the chosen type (when item is clicked, go to:)
- specific service view

Problem is that when I hit the auto-generated "Back" button from inside a specific service view, and expect to get back to the services list for the chosen type, the app does routes back to the list, he content is seen to about half a second, but then - ALL the content (including the top navbar) is hidden, and though, still clickable!
This also happens not just for the "Back" button but also when clicking a link from the specific service view to any arbitrary services list view.

Since the previous view is seen before disappearing, I conclude that the routing implementation is valid, but yet tried to use ui-route ui-sref and other approaches to navigation but couldn't solve this.

It happens both on chrome browser and android device.

My stateProvider config looks like that:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })
  .state('app.main', {
    url: '/main',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.services', {
    url: '/services/:tid',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/services.html',
        controller: 'ServicesCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.service', {
    url: '/service/:sid',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/service.html',
        controller: 'ServiceCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm having the same issue

Comment: I'm having the same issue as well in the iOS simulator and on-device builds. The DOM elements are still there, just not visible. I've verified this with the Safari inspector.